# Scroll different information in a div with the ability to go to the old one

Tags: javascript, html

What is it called when sites like nhl.com have the ability to scroll through 5 different stories in a single area on a time on the page while being able to click to the previous.

see http://nhl.com

i'm trying to find the correct word for it to google some examples.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean. If you're talking about the area with the Huge Picture, that can be done with

```
<input type='button' value='displayValue' id='someId' />
```

or

```
<button id='someId'>displayValue</button>
```

and JavaScript, like:

```
function E(e){
  return document.getElementById(e);
}
E('someId').onclick = function(){
  E('whereYourPicIsId').src = 'pic/Pic1.jpg'; //path to pic
}
```